# REST Webservice HTTP_PUT parameter

Tags: php, rest, base64, parameter-passing, http-put

I make with tonic (php library for rest ) a rest webservice.

I use according to CRUD and REST put for editing a element.

So i call my method with a picture and filetype and parse the paramters and save the base64 encoded file on my server.

Code:

```
function put($request) {

    $response = new Response($request);
    $msg = new ErrorMessage();
    $dbmodel = new DBModel();
    $arr = array('Data' => null,'Message' =>null,'Code' => null);
    try{
        $split = explode ('&',$request->data);
        $para = array();

        foreach($split as $i) {
            $names = explode('=',$i);
            if(!isset($names[0]) or !isset($names[1]))
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
            $para[$names[0]] = $names[1];
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        $arr['Code'] = 400;
        $arr['Message'] = $msg->getMessage(400);
        $response->body = json_encode($arr);
        return $response;
    }


    if (isset($para['picture']) or isset($para['filetype']) )
    {
        if (isset($para['picture']) and isset($para['filetype']))
        {
            if (!($para['filetype'] == 'jpg' || $para['filetype'] == 'png'))
            {
                $arr['Code'] = 688;
                $arr['Message'] = $msg->getMessage(617);
                $response->body = json_encode($arr);
                return $response;
            }
            $bin = base64_decode($para['picture']);
            if (strlen($bin) >524288)
            {
                $arr['Code'] = 617;
                $arr['Message'] = $msg->getMessage(617);
                $response->body = json_encode($arr);
                return $response;
            }

            $uid = $dbmodel->getUid($sid);
            if($uid<1)
            {
                $arr['Code'] = 699;
                $arr['Message'] = $msg->getMessage(699);
                $response->body = json_encode($arr);
                return $response;

            }
            $file = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/img/".$uid.".".$para['filetype'], 'wb');
            fwrite($file, $bin);
            fclose($file);

        }
        else
        {
            $arr['Code'] = 616;
            $arr['Message'] = $msg->getMessage(616);
            $response->body = json_encode($arr);
            return $response;
        }

    }

    $arr['Code'] = 200;
    $arr['Message'] = $msg->getMessage(200);
    $response->body = json_encode($arr);
    return $response;
}
```

Problem: The saved picture isn't like the original one it can't be displayed as image

I use http://www.redio.info/werkzeuge/file2base64.html to convert my picture into base64. I think that the problem could be in the parsing at the beginning of my code.

Original: 13.872 Bytes

New Image: 14.313 Bytes

Comment: Isn't like the original one... how?

Comment: Look at both files with a hexeditor (or even just a text editor) and look for obvious differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your picture parameter gets probably urlencoded, that would explain the bigger filesize. (e.g. '/' to %2F)

Try to put a urldecode around the parameter before you decode it.

```
$bin = base64_decode(urldecode($para['picture']));
```